# How do I seamlessly deploy a web app with hashed resources in kubernetes?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I want to deploy a Java application that uses a vue.js frontend.
Currently, I am using multiple pods in a Deployment, a ClusterIp Service and a nginx Ingress. The Ingress is running in round-robin mode.

The problem is as follows:

Fine before deployment:

- The application is deployed in version `1.0`.
- Version `1.0` provides a frontend that uses some resources with hashes in their name -- let's just say `1.0.js` and `1.0.css` (we will use versions instead of hashes to make it easier to read).
- A user requests the site, the site tells him to request `1.0.js` and he does so. The round-robin nginx will dispatch the request to another Pod that is also in version `1.0` and he can retreive the resource.

---

Broken during deplyoment:

- Version `2.0` is deployed, providing the all-new `2.0` frontend (`2.0.js` and `2.0.css`)
- During deployment, there are at least two Pods in the cluster that have different versions (`1.0` and `2.0`)
- A user requests the site and finishes up on a `2.0` Pod. The site tells him to request `2.0.js` and he does so. The round-robin nginx will dispatch the request for `2.0.js` to a `1.0` Pod that does not have the resource on hand -- the request fails (404, this will fail the other way around, too).

---

Fine after deployment:

- The deployment is finished, all pods are version `2.0`
- No more requests fail.

So during the development, requests will fail constantly. Having two pods, around 50% of the time the user will get a 404. This is not only be a problem with hashed resources (webpack etc.) but also with all other resources that only on version of the pod provides.

Is there a way to reduce these failed requests? Restrict new requests during deployment to new Pods maybe? I researched Ingress/Service LB but found nothing, am I missing the point?

Answer (score 1):

It's happening due to you having a **RollingUpdate** deployment strategy.

You can try implementing the **Canary** or **Blue-Green** deployment and I think that will resolve your issue.

With Nginx ingress, it's tricky to implement canary and Blue green however logic is like, once your all v2 PODs are deployed to cluster you update the **Lable** of service, so service will only forward the traffic to **V2** version pod.

Simple example by changing **labels** in service : https://www.sivalabs.in/2021/09/kubernetes-blue-green-deployments/

Above one is the simplest solution, you can manage the traffic and version using the service label.

**OR**

Instead of Nginx ingress, you can also use Istio service mesh or HAproxy to mange traffic routing very well

Example of Istio with canary deployment : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-do-canary-deployments-with-istio-and-kubernetes

Example of Istio with blue/green deployment :
https://thenewstack.io/tutorial-blue-green-deployments-with-kubernetes-and-istio/